# Git hanging when mirroring to Github via SSH

Tags: git, mirroring

I'm having an issue trying to setup a mirror on Github.

The repo is private and owned by an organization on Github.
I am part of this organization and have every right possible.

A clone of this repo is hosted on a development server.
A clone of this clone is hosted on every developer's computer.

When any of us push on the development server, I have a `post-receive` hook that mirrors our changes to the Github repo.

My hook is a simple :

```
git push github master
```

It works fine when I use an `https` URL for the remote like

```
https://user:pass@github.com/orga/project.git/
```

But it requires me to include my password into the remote URL, which isn't ideal.

I tried to use `SSH` instead:

```
git@github.com:orga/repo.git
```

I followed the guide on Github, created a public key on the development server and added it to my Github account.
But whenever I try to push on the server, it hangs when it tries to mirror on Github.

What am I missing?

Comment: With a reasonably up-to-date Git, you can run `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv" git push git@github.com:orga/repo.git` and see what the output from ssh to standard error is.  That output would be useful here, and it might help you track down the problem.

Comment: To verify that your SSH key works, run `ssh git@github.com` from your development server. It should tell you that you're successfully authenticated. If it works, try `git push` manually and see if it works or prints something.

Comment: bk2204 command solved it for me

Answer (score 0):

Github is having issues right now.  I would wait until they are back up and running normally before trying it again.

Comment: I've been having this issue for 3 days now, Github was fine then